# how to handle timeouts in getimagesize()

Tags: php

I am trying to find image/pixel size for an image before I use it. I see the following warning for an image.
`Warning: getimagesize(http://farm4.hv-static.flickr.com/3052/2330936325_ea1ddf9e7d_m.jpg): failed to open stream: Connection timed out`
Any idea how one can handle this? I checked the manual but didnt find any option.

Answer (score 0):

getimagesize returns FALSE if retrieving is failed.
you can disable warnings output if you don't want to see them by

```
error_reporting(0);
```

Comment: well, my organisation would not permit me to use error_reporting(0)

Comment: Then stick an `ob_start()` before it, and an `ob_end_clean()` after it, which will swallow the error in the Output Buffer and then discard of it. If anything, preventing you from using `error_reporting(0)` would be a BAD thing, from the point of view of customer experience, in my opinion - users don't like errors which break things.

Answer (score 0):

As [its manual page says](http://fr.php.net/getimagesize) :

> If accessing the filename image is
> impossible, or if it isn't a valid
> picture, `getimagesize()` will
> generate an error of level
> `E_WARNING`. 
> On read error,
> `getimagesize()` will generate an
> error of level `E_NOTICE`.

There is not much you can do about that, except **making sure the error message is not displayed** to your users.

This can be done changing the [**`display_errors`**][2] directive:

- in your php.ini file, for all your pages *(good idea : it's never great to display errors on a production server)*
- or using `ini_set('display_errors', 'off');` at the beginning of your script.

Or using the [**`@` operator**][3], to silence the error :

```
$result = @getimagesize(...);
```

Note : this is generally not quite a good idea : you'll totally loose the indication that an error occured !

It's better to not display the error, but still have it logged...

Comment: it seems there is no way out, I will have to use @